# factorisations overs matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Can anyone explain to me this passage 
Given to matix $A$ and $B$ taht commutes and $q$ a positive integer 
when you consider the polynomial $X^{2q+1}+1$ it has as roots $\{-1,\alpha_1,......,\alpha_q,\beta_1,......,\beta_q\}$ such that the $\beta_i$'s are the conjugates of the $\alpha_i$'s
than $A^{2q+1}+B^{2q+1}=(A+B)\prod_{k=1}^{q} (A+\alpha_k B)(A+\beta_k B)$
could anyone help me to understand this please ?

Comment: What is it that you don't understand? Are you asking what it says, or are you asking why it's true?

Comment: thank you sir I understood it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the factorisation (over $\mathbf C$):
$$X^{2q+1}+1=(X+1)\prod_{k=1}^q(X-\alpha_k)(X-\beta_k)$$
(note there's a sign error in your formula) you can deduce by homogeneisation the factorisation (set $X=Y/Z$ and multiply both sides by $Z^{2q+1}$):
$$Y^{2q+1}+Z^{2q+1}=(Y+Z)\prod_{k=1}^q(Y-\alpha_kZ)(Y-\beta_kZ)$$
Now in this polynomial $\in\mathbf C[Y,Z]$, you can substitute $A$ and $B$ to $Y$ and $Z$ respectively, since $A$ and $B$ commute.